# Copying Java ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I have a `java.sql.ResultSet` object that I need to update. However the result set is not updatable. Unfortunately this is a constraint on the particular framework I'm using.

What I'm trying to achieve here is taking data from a database, then manipulating a small amount of the data and finally the data is being written to a CSV file.

At this stage I think my best option is to create a new result set object and copy the contents of the original result set into the new one, manipulating the data as I do so.

However, I've hunted high and low on Google and don't seem to be able to determine how to do this or whether it's even possible at all.

I'm new to everything Java so any assistance would be gratefully received.

Comment: Answer taken from - http://www.coderanch.com/t/294658/JDBC/databases/clone-ResultSet
Strictly a class which implements ResultSet doesn't hold any data. Drivers are free to go back to the database for each "next()". This is why a ResultSet is usually neither serializable nor cloneable.
What almost everyone does is read the results into some other data structure (a 2d array, a Vector of arrays, an ArrayList of Maps, whatever.) You can make that data structure serializable or cloneable if you wish.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. In the end I found `CachedRowSet` which is exactly what I needed. With this I was able to disconnect the `ResultSet` object and update it.

What's more, because `CachedRowSet` implements the `ResultSet` interface I was still able to pass it to my file generation method which requires an object that implements ResultSet.

Answer (score 10):

The normal practice would be to map the `ResultSet` to a `List<Entity>` where `Entity` is your own class which contains information about the data represented by a single database row. E.g. `User`, `Person`, `Address`, `Product`, `Order`, etcetera, depending on what the table actually contains.

```
List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
// ...
while (resultSet.next()) {
    Entity entity = new Entity();
    entity.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));
    entity.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
    entity.setValue(resultSet.getInt("value"));
    // ...
    entities.add(entity);
}
// ...
return entities;
```

Then, you can access, traverse and modify it the usual Java way. Finally, when persisting it back in the DB, use a `PreparedStatement` to update them in batches in a single go.

```
String sql = "UPDATE entity SET name = ?, value = ? WHERE id = ?";
// ...
statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
for (Entity entity : entities) {
    statement.setString(1, entity.getName());
    statement.setInt(2, entity.getValue());
    statement.setLong(3, entity.getId());
    // ...
    statement.addBatch();
}
statement.executeBatch();
// ...
```

Note that some DB's have a limit on the batch size. Oracle's JDBC driver has a limit on around 1000 items. You may want to call `executeBatch()` every 1000 items then. It should be simple using a counter inside the loop.

#### See also:

- [Collections tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html)
- [PreparedStatement tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: Hi - thanks for the great response. In this situation - the data is being pull from the db, there will be a small amount of manipulation and then the data is being written to a CSV file.

Comment: If the manipulation is row-based, then just do it inside the `while` loop and write it immediately as a new line of CSV file. By the way, the average DB ships with CSV export facilities which can do it more efficient than you can ever do in Java. It's unclear which one you're using, so here's just a MySQL based example: `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Comment: @BalusC - wouldn't it be better to use an ETL tool for such jobs, if you have access to one ?