# Why does set1 get null when set goes null?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

In the following snippet I execute a query and pass the result set to `set`. Then the `set` is assigned to `set1`. After that there is a while loop which goes on until `set.next` returns `false`. Is it that if `set.next` returns false after the loop,`set1` will also return false ?

```
ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();
ResultSet set1 = set;
while (set.next()) {
    if (set.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase(keyword)) { 
        // If the search matches the exact keyword
        list.put(set.getString(2), set.getString(1));
        // Where key is the name of the node and value is, name of the file
    }
}
```

I asked this because:

```
while (set1.next()) {
    System.out.println("@@@Inside the while statement@@@");
    if (set1.getString(1).contains(keyword) 
    && set1.getString(1).compareToIgnoreCase(keyword) !=0) { 
        // If the search contains the keyword but does not exactly match
        list.put(set.getString(2), set.getString(1));
        // Where key is the name of the node and value is, name of the file
        System.out.println("@@@Inside the if statement of second while loop !@@@");
    }
}
```

This `while` construct never works. Is that the reason ? If that is, what do I do ?

Comment: You've already iterated through the ResultSet. Please understand that while you have two ResultSet *variables*, they both refer to the very same ResultSet *object*. So if you've iterated through the object and calling `next()` on the one variable returns false, then it will be false, no matter which variable you call the method on.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels but I assigned `set` to `set1` before the iteration

Comment: It doesn't matter. Again set and set1 refer to the very same object.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels so is there a way to duplicate the object keeping their souls different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two major bugs:

1. Assigning `set` to `set1` doesn't make a copy - it's the same set
2. `String.contains()` is *case sensitive* (your code doesn't match your comments)

The fix is:

1. Don't use two loops - use just one loop
2. Use `` `toLowerCase() `` with `contains()` to achieve a "case insensitive contains" test
3. Also, if your first test is true, so is your second, so you don't need two tests/loops anyway

Try this code:

```
   ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();
   while(set.next()) {
       if(set.getString(1).toLowerCase()
              .contains(keyword.toLowerCase)) {
           list.put(set.getString(2), set.getString(1));
       }
   }
```

Also, don't call a map "list" - call it "map", otherwise it's just going to confuse readers of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this .

```
   ResultSet set1 = statement.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

`set1` is a reference to the same object that `set` points to. If you want to iterate over the `ResultSet` again, you need to move the iterator cursor to the beginning again using something like:

```
set.beforeFirst();
```

In Java, assigning a variable to an object doesn't make a copy of the object, it only references the object in memory. You would have to explicitly make a copy of the object if you wanted `set` and `set1` to work independently.

In your particular use case, I don't think that's what you want, it seems better to just move the iteration cursor.

Comment: If you absolutely MUST get a copy of the `ResultSet` object, I'd suggest looking at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817785/copying-java-resultset

Answer (score 0):

> *Is it that if `set.next` returns false after the loop,`set1` will also
>   return false ?*

**YES**. Because `set1` is referring the same object of `Resultset` which `set` is referring. So whatever behavior is exhibited by the `ResultSet` object referenced by `set` will also be reflected by `set1`.In your first while loop the `ResultSet` object referenced by `set` is exhausted completely after iterating to all records (using set.next()) . Thereafter no matter which variable (set or set1) tries to read more both will get `.next()` as `false`.

If in Your first while loop construct I check `.next()` using `set` variable and get the result using `set1` variable it still will work. 
Try this code instead of your first construct and you will see that output is same as what you have written in your first while construct:

```
ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();
       ResultSet set1 = set;
       while(set.next()) {
           if(set1.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase(keyword)) { // If the search matches the exact keyword
               list.put(set1.getString(2), set1.getString(1));
               // Where key is the name of the node and value is, name of the file
           }
       }
```

If you still want `set1` to return results you should reconstruct a new `ResultSet` object using :

```
set1 = stat.executeQuery()
```

where, `stat` is the `Statement/PreparedStatement` whatever you are using in your code.